# Does 2D dot product, with negative second member has a special name?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

We have two vectors: $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^2$

The dot product is: $a_x * b_x + a_y * b_y$

But I see this formula, on many papers/articles: $a_x * b_x - a_y * b_y$

What is this formula called?

Comment: Dont you mean instead $a_x * b_y - a_y * b_x$ and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$? If such is the case, an answer is that it is the area of the  parallelogram generated by $(a_x,a_y), (b_x,b_y)$. Another answer is that it is the $z$ component of the **cross** product of 3D vectors $(a_x,a_y,0), (b_x,b_y,0)$

Comment: No. I see it for example in the equation of the complex multiplication (real part `ac - bd`)

Comment: Do we agree at least that it is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It is in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no name attached to this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is this:

A real inner product space with a bilinear form with signature all $1$'s except for a single $-1$ (or all $-1$'s with a single $1$) is called a [Minkowski metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space).